# After installing bootstrap and jquery and popper.js , Nothing was displaying on my live server but no error was detected after compiling

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

After installing bootstrap and jquery and popper.js , Nothing was displaying on my live server but no error was detected after compiling

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'jquery/src/jquery.js'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'

createApp(App).mount('#app')


<script>
import Home from './components/Home.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Home
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure about what file is this. Can you provide more context? How do you run the provided file? It does look like both a html file and a js file. If they are separate files, you should put them in different section instead of putting them in the same code block.

Answer (score 0):

You installed properly?

> npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta popper.js jquery

Comment: i did npm install bootstrap popper.js jquery --save instead......do i have to do dis npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta popper.js jquery